# Conditionally create new column in Spark (scala) dynamically

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to create a new conditional column in spark, which is filled in from an existing column that is selected programatically, and based on the processed outputs of a third column.

Apologies is this sounds complicated, but here is an example. Sample df:

```
// sample df
val df = Seq(
  (1, "2014/07/31 23:00:01", 1, 2), 
  (1, "2014/07/30 12:40:32", 3, 3), 
  (1, "2016/08/09 10:12:43", 5, 6))
.toDF("id", "date", "7_col", "8_col")
.withColumn("timestamp", unix_timestamp($"date", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").cast("timestamp"))

+---+-------------------+-----+-----+-------------------+
| id|               date|7_col|8_col|          timestamp|
+---+-------------------+-----+-----+-------------------+
|  1|2014/07/31 23:00:01|    1|    2|2014-07-31 23:00:01|
|  1|2014/07/30 12:40:32|    3|    3|2014-07-30 12:40:32|
|  1|2016/08/09 10:12:43|    5|    6|2016-08-09 10:12:43|
+---+-------------------+-----+-----+-------------------+
```

Now, I would like to create a new column, which is filled in with the contents of either `7_col` or `8_col`, depending on whether the month in the `timestamp` col is the 7th month (`7_col`) or the 8th month (`8_col`). So the result should look like so:

```
+---+-------------------+-----+-----+-------------------+-------+
| id|               date|7_col|8_col|          timestamp|new_col|
+---+-------------------+-----+-----+-------------------+-------+
|  1|2014/07/31 23:00:01|    1|    2|2014-07-31 23:00:01|      1|
|  1|2014/07/30 12:40:32|    3|    3|2014-07-30 12:40:32|      3|
|  1|2016/08/09 10:12:43|    5|    6|2016-08-09 10:12:43|      6|
+---+-------------------+-----+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

Now, I can partially do this programatically if I simply pass the month as an `Int` and interpolate it into the input of name of the column to pass, like so:

```
df.withColumn("new_col", $"${7}_col" ).show 

+---+-------------------+-----+-----+-------------------+-------+
| id|               date|7_col|8_col|          timestamp|new_col|
+---+-------------------+-----+-----+-------------------+-------+
|  1|2014/07/31 23:00:01|    1|    2|2014-07-31 23:00:01|      1|
|  1|2014/07/30 12:40:32|    3|    3|2014-07-30 12:40:32|      3|
|  1|2016/08/09 10:12:43|    5|    6|2016-08-09 10:12:43|      5|
+---+-------------------+-----+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

However, when instead of the digit I try to pass the extracted month from the `timestamp` column, it fails to work:

```
df.withColumn("new_col", $"${month($"timestamp")}_col").show 

Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`month(timestamp)_col`' given input columns: [7_col, id, date, 8_col, timestamp];
```

Now, I know that the code to extract the month works and results in an `Int` result, so for example I can simply fill my `new_col` with the extracted month `Int` like so:

```
df.withColumn("new_col", month($"timestamp")).show 

+---+-------------------+-----+-----+-------------------+-------+
| id|               date|7_col|8_col|          timestamp|new_col|
+---+-------------------+-----+-----+-------------------+-------+
|  1|2014/07/31 23:00:01|    1|    2|2014-07-31 23:00:01|      7|
|  1|2014/07/30 12:40:32|    3|    3|2014-07-30 12:40:32|      7|
|  1|2016/08/09 10:12:43|    5|    6|2016-08-09 10:12:43|      8|
+---+-------------------+-----+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

But I cannot figure out why I cannot pass such an Int and interpolate it into the column name.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `when.otherwise`:

```
df.withColumn("new_col", when(month($"timestamp") === 7, $"7_col").otherwise($"8_col")).show
+---+-------------------+-----+-----+-------------------+-------+
| id|               date|7_col|8_col|          timestamp|new_col|
+---+-------------------+-----+-----+-------------------+-------+
|  1|2014/07/31 23:00:01|    1|    2|2014-07-31 23:00:01|      1|
|  1|2014/07/30 12:40:32|    3|    3|2014-07-30 12:40:32|      3|
|  1|2016/08/09 10:12:43|    5|    6|2016-08-09 10:12:43|      6|
+---+-------------------+-----+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

---

Another option to handle `month_col` dynamically:

```
val months = (7 to 8).map(m => when(month(col("timestamp")) === m, col(s"${m}_col")))
//       change 7 to 8 to a sequence of all exsiting months columns

df.withColumn("new_col", coalesce(months: _*)).show
+---+-------------------+-----+-----+-------------------+-------+
| id|               date|7_col|8_col|          timestamp|new_col|
+---+-------------------+-----+-----+-------------------+-------+
|  1|2014/07/31 23:00:01|    1|    2|2014-07-31 23:00:01|      1|
|  1|2014/07/30 12:40:32|    3|    3|2014-07-30 12:40:32|      3|
|  1|2016/08/09 10:12:43|    5|    6|2016-08-09 10:12:43|      6|
+---+-------------------+-----+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks Psidom. I am currently using the `.when` `.otherwise` code, but was looking for something that would work dynamically - your second answer does the job!